# information about the underlying data-model behind civicrm (version 4.6)

Tags: data-model

where can I find that? I have a good knowledge of databases, so this information would help me a lot in modeling the civicrm-data with either contact-tags, groups.

Answer (score 3):

There is some data information on the wiki:

- https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Database+Reference    -
- https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+data+architecture
- https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+4.4+ER+Diagram

I hope this helps you!